# What's the equation for calculating normal vector at a point?

Tags: orthonormal

What's the equation for calculating normal vector at a point?

Particularly I'm trying understand the function given [here](https://git.net9.org/wyl8899/ray_tracer/blob/d7c9a2f3a6e11e8a47daa4cd25b26f8725090a1e/src/Object.cpp#L59):

```
Vec3f Sphere::GetNormalAt(const Vec3f &pos) const {   
    return cv::normalize(pos - points[o]); 
}
```

So what exactly is this as an equation?

It's some kind of

$$\frac{pos-p}{||pos-p||}$$

but what point is $p$?

Also, I'm particularly trying to get this function in order to use here:
https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/tag/ray/
where you see the function getNormalAt() being used for something in Ray-Sphere interaction.

Additionally [here](http://theses.cz/id/xenqhh/Bakalarska_prace/src/Geometry-5_8/Geometry/GraphicObjects/Quadrics/Shapes/Elipsoid/Elipsoid.cs) one can find the function with some algebra:

```
private Vector GetNormalAt(Vector v)
{
    double x = (2 / (_a * _a)) * v.GetX();
    double y = (2 / (_b * _b)) * v.GetY();
    double z = (2 / (_c * _c)) * v.GetZ();
    Vector normal = new Vector(x, y, z);
    normal.NornVector();
    return normal * -_normalSign;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what programming language that is. Can you write it as pseudo-code? Should it be a normal vector that is normal to another vector, a field, or what? Please give some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looking at the function, it is a method of a `sphere` class.

Consider a sphere and a point $p$ on the sphere, of radius $r$, with center $c$.

The normal at $p$ is pointing in the same direction as $n = p - c$ (i.e. pointing outward from the center of the sphere).
Thus, the unit normal is just:
$$
n(p) = \frac{p-c}{||p-c||_2}
$$
So I can only assume $c$ is the point to which you are referring.

The second class you link to is an `ellipsoid` class. Again, the calculation is specific to that surface.

---

For reference, in general, one computes surface normals by finding two linearly independent tangent vectors to the surface $T_1(p)$ and $T_2(p)$ at point $p$, and computing the normal as:
$$
n(p) = \frac{T_1(p)\times T_2(p)}{||T_1(p)\times T_2(p)||_2}
$$

(The cases you are looking at have special geometry such that this is not required.)